# Understanding the proof of theorem 7.4 in Conway's book "Functions of one complex variable":

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Consider the following fragment on p99 of Conway's book "Functions of one complex variable":
[image]

I don't fully understand this proof.

(1) Firstly, what are the $z_k(\zeta)$ for $1 \le k \le p$? Are they the zeros of $f(z)-\alpha$ inside $B(a, \epsilon)?$ If so, why are there only finitely many such zeros?

Maybe because otherwise $\overline{B}(a,\epsilon)$ has infinitely many zeros, and has therefore a limit point by compactness. But I don't see how to proceed then.

(2) How exactly does the equality $n(\sigma, \zeta) = \sum_{k=1}^p n(\gamma, z_k(\zeta))$ ensure that there are exactly $m$ solutions of $f(z) = \zeta$ inside $B(a, \epsilon)$?

Comment: what the author is doing is applying the Argument Principle, albeit skipping some steps.  For 1, basically yes. Re: finitely many zeros in a compact set: You know zeros of non-constant analytic function $g$ are isolated, so for some compact set $K$ select an open ball around each point that has at most one (distinct) zero in $K$ and $K= \bigcup_{z\in K}\{z\} \subseteq \bigcup_{z\in K}B\big(z, \rho^{(z)}\big)$ (where $\rho^{(z)}$ is the radius and depends on each point $z$).  This open cover has a finite sub-cover by compactness so there are finitely many zeros in $K$.

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks! That solves (1) completely for me. What about (2)?

Comment: @user8675309 the $z_k$ are not the zeroes of $f(z)-\alpha$ inside $B(a;\varepsilon)$. They are the zeroes of $f(z)-\zeta$ inside it where $|\alpha-\zeta|<\delta$. It’s a subtle difference, but it’s very important in this proof.

Comment: @PhilipSpeegle -- fair enough... they are the points in $f^{-1}(\zeta)$, that are inside the closed curve (given by $\gamma$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On page 98, Conway defines the object $z_k(\zeta)$ to be the points satisfying $f(z)=\zeta$. On the other hand,

$$ n(\sigma;\alpha) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\sigma \frac{\mathrm dw}{w-\alpha}$$

which is

$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f’(z)}{f(z)-\alpha}.$$

This counts the amount of zeroes of $f(z)-\alpha$ inside $B(a;\varepsilon)$. But remember—we explicitly made sure that $f(z)-\alpha$ has *no* solution with $0<|z-\alpha|<2\varepsilon$. Therefore, the only zero it will count is the one with order $m$ at $a$, whence $n(\sigma;\alpha) =m$.

But also, we specifically chose $\gamma$ such that $\alpha\notin \{\sigma\}$. Therefore, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that the entirety of $B(\alpha;\delta)$ belongs to the same component of $\mathbb C-\{\sigma\}$. Intuitively, the winding number of $\sigma$ about $\alpha$ counts the amount of times $\sigma$ wraps around $\alpha$, so for any $\zeta$ such that $|\alpha-\zeta|<\delta$, $n(\sigma;\alpha) = n(\sigma;\zeta)$.

But by the same integral that we did above,

$$n(\sigma;\zeta)=\sum_{k=1}^p n(\gamma;z_k(\zeta))$$

where $z_k(\zeta)$ are the points in $B(a;\varepsilon)$ such that $f(z)=\zeta$ (remember, this is the same thing as counting the zeroes of $f(z)-\zeta$). This implies that there are $m$ of these solutions because $n(\gamma;z)$ can only be zero or one (intuitively, $\gamma$ can wrap around a point at most once). All of them must be simple because we chose $\varepsilon$ such that $f’(z)\ne 0$ on $0<|z-a|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks!